# What software program can I use to build a custom desktop keyboard IME for MacOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I would like to make my own version of Mac's ABC-Extended keyboard for typing Pinyin (a way to write Mandarin that indicates tones). But when I use Xcode, I just see a target custom keyboard extension for iOS and nothing for macOS. I've looked into the program Ukulele but it doesn't seem like it will do everything I need. Theoretically I could also put my rules into files like how [this article](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-use-your-own-input-source-on-mac-mchlp2866/12.0/mac/12.0) indicates but that also seems cumbersome based on what I want my keyboard to do.

Here's what I want it to do:

- First option: user literally types "ni3 hao3" and my logic in real time changes their output to "nǐ hǎo" (there are pinyin/grammar rules for where the tone mark goes)
- Secondly (phase 2 in my project), in their user settings for the keyboard, they could indicate they want to convert their text to Hanzi (the characters). So when they type their Pinyin, my algorithm guesses a best guess list of Hanzi characters that matches their Pinyin entry. This would require that I have a downloaded dictionary file for my keyboard.

Thanks for any help! I know how to program it I just need the right software to use :(

Comment: Btw, I'm curious what software the company Sogou uses for their mac version keyboard: https://pinyin.sogou.com/mac/

Answer (score 1):

One option (but probably not practical for a project of the scope you envision) would be to use Apple's own [Custom IM creator](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-use-your-own-input-source-on-mac-mchlp2866/12.0/mac/12.0).

An example of one of these for only ni3 hao3 can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xdmiptqy44thun/nihao.inputplugin.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks Tom! (And sorry for the delayed response.) That's close to what I'm thinking.  This other web page though https://developer.apple.com/documentation/inputmethodkit from Apple seems promising and then I came across this which is more specific as to implementation https://www.logcg.com/en/archives/2078.html. I'll need to play around with this a bit more but thought I'd at least respond to you.